# method `strftime' for "2/25/2014 10:20":String. Convert to Joba time

Tags: ruby

So im trying to make a script that convert the item behind the `"properties{"CreationDate"]`to Joda-Time. But i keep getting errors.

Creationdate is a properties field in my program with a date 2/25/2014 10:20. but i want it in Joba-time. Like this: 2014 M2 25, Wed 10:20:09 GMT+02:00

so i cant make a script where i type in the date, as the date is behind the creationdate. And there will be alot of dates behind that one.

I cant use the date in my code, as there will be alot of difference date behind "creationdate"

```
require 'date'
items = $current_selected_items
items.each do |email|
properties = email.getProperties
date_time = properties["CreationDate"]
date_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
date_time.strftime("%Y M%m %d, %a %H:%M:%S %Z")
             end
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `strftime' for "2/25/2014 10:20":String
Did you mean?  strip
  block in (root) at <script>:6
           <main> at <script>:3
Script failed due to an error:
org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (NoMethodError) undefined method `strftime' for "2/25/2014 10:20":String
Did you mean?  strip
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:131)
    at org.jruby.embed.jsr223.JRubyEngine.eval(JRubyEngine.java:90)
    at org.jruby.embed.jsr223.JRubyEngine.eval(JRubyEngine.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.nuix.script.e.a(SourceFile:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.nuix.script.e.a(SourceFile:56)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.nuix.script.j.a(SourceFile:53)
    at com.nuix.investigator.script.m.e(SourceFile:326)
    at com.nuix.investigator.script.m.c(SourceFile:277)
    at com.nuix.investigator.script.m.doInBackground(SourceFile:180)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoMethodError) undefined method `strftime' for "2/25/2014 10:20":String
Did you mean?  strip
    at RUBY.block in (root)(<script>:6)
    at RUBY.<main>(<script>:3)
```

Comment: Convert `date_time` before using strftime.

Comment: Im brand new to ruby, startet 1-2 days ago. How do i convert it :S ?

Comment: You can use Date.strptime and pass the string to convert and a format string.

Comment: @DanielOppenlænder The question was marked as a duplicate. If you click the link above, you will see that this answers your question fully.

Comment: @Tom Lord The question is not answered fully. Iknow how to code it so it change 1 date,but that is not what im looking for, im looking for chaning dates from aproperties string.

Comment: @Sebastián Palma So i want to convert the time behind the  varible properties["CreationDate"]

Comment: You need to access its value before converting it, I think otherwise is impossible.

Comment: @DanielOppenlænder I don't see what you're having trouble with here... What's the problem with using `DateTime.strptime(properties["CreationDate"], ...)`?

Comment: So i have tried that with this code
`require 'date'
items = $current_selected_items
items.each do |email|
properties = email.getProperties
puts DateTime.strptime(properties["CreationDate"], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
             .strftime('%Y M%m %d, %a %H:%M:%S %Z')
             end`

Comment: Error: Script failed due to an error:
org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (ArgumentError) invalid date

Comment: See the answer, and note the difference in the format being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable in which you're using strftime is an String, that means you must convert it in order to use strftime on it.

You could use strptime passing the correct format, something similar to what you're using in "`date_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`", try with:

```
require 'date'
string = DateTime.strptime(properties['CreationDate'], '%d/%M/%Y %H:%M')
puts string.strftime("%Y M%m %d, %a %H:%M:%S %Z")
```